# Convert List[Any] to tuple with different type values

Tags: scala

I trying convert List[Any] to tuple with some data types.

```
def matchValue(list: List[Any]):(Int, Int, Int, Option[String], String,Option[Date],String, Date,String, Option[Int],Option[String])= {
      list match {
        case i1::i2::i3::i4::i5::i6::i7::i8::i9::i10::i11 => (i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11)
      }
    }
```

but i have error:

> Expression of type Any doesn't conform to expected type Int

Comment: What's the initial use case? I could just throw you [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), but I'm not sure if it's the correct solution.

Comment: I try convert data in order to import it to db with slick

Comment: You're trying to do a bunch of implicit conversions here. Your error is say that since the first element is an Any, you can't force it into an Int, which the first element in a returned Tuple must be, according to your return type. You could write [conversions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions) from Any to each type you require and place them in scope, though this seems excessive. It seems that you may be parsing rows of input. If that's true, then you can use existing [marshallers](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-httpx/marshalling/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
case (i1: Int) :: (i2: Int) :: // etc
```

1. If you have many similar cases with different target tuples, you indeed want something like shapeless (same tuple sizes can be handled).
2. `: Option[String]` pattern can actually only check the argument is an `Option`. You'll get a warning about this, which can be ignored by using `Option[String @unchecked]`, but it should only be done if you are sure you'll really get an `Option[String]`.

Comment: @K.Palyanichka this solution is actually preferable than mine. But you now know that you can convert "imperatively" any value to another using `asInstanceOf` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert each value to its primitive type using `x.asInstanceOf[T]`. So for example `x.asIntanceOf[Int]` will convert any `x` to an `Int`.